# css for checkbox while hover

Tags: css

I wanna change  color for each checkbox while hover.I have four checkbox.I wanna change the color, If I hover the 'all' checkbox it shows red,blue color for 'cold',orange for 'warm' and green for 'Active'.

```css
#ck-button {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}
#ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 4.0em;
}
#ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
input:checked +span {
  background-color: #911;
  color: #fff;
}
#ck-button input:hover #all + span {
  background-color: #efE0E0;
}
#ck-button input:hover #o1 + span {
  background-color: blue;
}
#ck-button input:hover #o2 + span {
  background-color: orange;
}
#ck-button input:hover #o3 + span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id=all value="All" checked><span>All</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o1" value="Cold" onclick=handleClick1(this.val);><span class="o1">Cold</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o2" value="Warm" onclick="handleClick1(this.val);"><span>Warm</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="sta_choice" id="o3" value="Active" onclick="handleClick1(this.val);"><span>Active</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Note for future: `enter code here` is not a valid way to escape the pre-requisite of inlining code in the question when posting a jsfiddle link...I've edited your question to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last four lines use `label:hover` instead of `input:hover`. Input is positioned to top and isn't hovered (is outside the label).

```
#ck-button label:hover #all + span {
    background-color:#efE0E0;
}
#ck-button label:hover #o1 + span {
    background-color:blue;
}
#ck-button label:hover #o2 + span {
    background-color:orange;
}
#ck-button label:hover #o3 + span {
    background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3q4uuvum/3/

Comment: shall I do  the same for input checked

Answer (score 0):

even as an option

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 25px auto;    
}
ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
input{
    display: none;
}
label{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
label:hover{
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
input:checked ~ label{    
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/themes/html5doctor2/images/HTML5_Badge_64.png) no-repeat center center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c1"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c2"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c3"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="checkbox" checked />  
        <label for="c4"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c5"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c6" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c6"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c7" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c7"></label>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c8" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c8"></label>
    <li>    
        <input type="checkbox" id="c9" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c9"></label>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find online how to display different colors for hover depending if the box is checked, but after tirelessly tweaking the code I figured it out.

```
.ck-button-class:hover input:checked + span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

This is assuming you assigned the class to these buttons, `<div id="ck-button" class="ck-button-class">`.